# Updating database using dataset only updates doesn't insert

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a grid view in asp.net which I am populating like this:

```
     sda1 = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from tran_dtls where tc='" + tcdropDown.SelectedValue + "'and doc_no='" + DocNoTxt.Text + "'", con);
     build = new SqlCommandBuilder(sda1);
     sda1.Fill(ds);                      //ds is a data set
     GridView1.DataSource = ds;
     GridView1.DataBind();
```

I  update the grid view by  passing the ds to a new data table, adding a new row in datatable then again binding the datatable to the grid:

```
       dt = (DataTable)ViewState["myViewState"];
              dt = ds.Tables[0];
              dr = dt.NewRow();
              dr["TC"] = Session["TC"];
              dr["sr_no"] = Session["i"].ToString(); //I have more fields but for simplicity only displaying few
              dt.Rows.Add(dr);
              dt.AcceptChanges();
              ViewState["myViewState"] = dt;

              Session["gridRow"] = dt;
```

Everything is smooth uptil now ,but when I try to update the database(after inserting new entries in the dataset) it doesn't work the save button code is below:

```
 protected void onSaveClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        dt = (DataTable)Session["gridRow"];// I am passing the data table in a session    as I am entering the new entry from a pop up window
        dt.GetChanges(DataRowState.Modified);


        sda1.Fill(dt);

        sda1.Update(dt);   
    }
```

Funny part is when I edit a the existing entry in dt it does edit(classic sql update) but it never insert any new entries which are added in the data table ,and it doesn't even throw a error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line

```
dt.AcceptChanges();
```

marks all rows in the datatable as Unchanged.

When you call

```
dt.GetChanges(DataRowState.Modified);
```

you get only the rows modified after the AcceptChanges()

Moreover, to get the rows Added to the database the correct statement will be

```
dt.GetChanges(DataRowState.Added);
```

but, as I have said, this will return nothing due to the AcceptChanges() call.
You should remove the AcceptChanges() statement.
Also, I don't think you need to call this in the logic of the save button

```
sda1.Fill(dt);
```

Comment: TY,it working now for some reason I had not written the same for edit and thats why it was working for edit,thanks again